# strtod - Problem in converting string to double

Tags: c, char, double, strtod

I have a very small program which converts a string to double. The problem is everytime it is printing 0.0000.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here

$ export LT_LEAK_START=1.5
$ echo $LT_LEAK_START
  1.5

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double d;
  d=strtod(getenv("LT_LEAK_START"), NULL);
  printf("d = %lf\n",d);
}
Output:
d=0.0000000
```

Comment: @Raveline: Thanks Raveline. It was useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try including

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: @codaddict: If stdlib.h is required, by `strtod`, then why it doesn't give error on compiling? How to use it in C++? #include <stdlib> will work?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: You're not compiling with warnings. For gcc, use `-Wall`. For c++ `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: @Erik: I guess, without `-Wall` also gcc gives warnings for incompatible type conversions etc. Doesn't it? Then why `-Wall` for this case?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: It's not a language error to use an undeclared function. It just has funny effects like assuming a function returns int if it's not declared. You should always compile with `-Wall`, it catches a lot of common mistakes.

Comment: @Codaddict: Thanks codaddict.

Answer (score 1):

you aren't including the strtod decl header (stdlib.h) so you are using an internal strtod implementation (which seems to be just a stub?)

```
root@pinkpony:~# gcc -Wall -g  -o t t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtod’
t.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getenv’
t.c:8: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
root@pinkpony:~# gdb ./t
Reading symbols from /root/t...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/t 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a96b64 in ____strtod_l_internal (nptr=<value optimized out>, endptr=<value optimized out>, group=<value optimized out>, loc=0x7ffff7dd6580) at strtod_l.c:530
5    30     strtod_l.c: No such file or directory.
        in strtod_l.c
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a96b64 in ____strtod_l_internal (nptr=<value optimized out>, endptr=<value optimized out>, group=<value optimized out>, loc=0x7ffff7dd6580) at strtod_l.c:530
#1  0x00000000004005bc in main () at t.c:6
(gdb)
```

ignore the sigsegv, on my platform is caused by getenv() which is declared as well in stdlib but has no internal gcc impl